# Why doesn't Opera play Last.fm? How can I get it to work?

Tags: opera, audio-streaming, internet-radio, last.fm

How can I get Opera to play Last.fm? http://www.last.fm/listen/globaltags/feel%20good

I'm using version 12.02, Windows XP.

Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.02

Description: Shockwave Flash 11.4 r402
C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_11_4_402_287.dll

application/futuresplash    FutureSplash movie  spl

application/x-shockwave-flash   Adobe Flash movie   swf

Comment: I've recreated the scenario in an XP virtual machine, but it works on my machine. What have you tried? Is this a problem with other websites? Did you install the Flash Player plugin?

Comment: Can you give a sample URL where I can try to play music?

Comment: @galacticninja Ok I edited it.

Comment: @Randolph West It works on Youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure we can solve your problem since your last.fm link plays correctly here with Opera 12.12

1. download [newest Opera](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/) from here
2. install Opera in [**portable mode**](http://www.google.de/imgres?um=1&hl=de&safe=off&sa=N&tbo=d&biw=1916&bih=989&tbm=isch&tbnid=kSnsmGc3mUKCxM:&imgrefurl=http://www.jkwebtalks.com/2010/10/run-opera-11-in-portable-mode.html&docid=iukPJKqYl0q5HM&imgurl=http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_O-HJgvcZDok/TMQ2I5H-VoI/AAAAAAAAD6w/EQ1dNQ1xo4U/s800/Opera-11--1.png&w=451&h=373&ei=STreUJWpB4j6sgbt3IDoDg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=390&vpy=669&dur=1108&hovh=204&hovw=247&tx=129&ty=126&sig=111661456705052104725&page=1&tbnh=143&tbnw=173&start=0&ndsp=59&ved=1t:429,r:42,s:0,i:219) (That way it won't mess up your current Opera)
3. download the [Adobe Flash Removal](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html) tool
   uninstall all Flash versions using the removal tool
4. download newest Adobe Flash Player. Be careful and choose *Flash Player 11 for Other Browsers*
5. Install Adobe Flash Player
6. Open your newly created Opera Browser and check if [your last.fm link](http://www.lastfm.de/listen/globaltags/feel%20good) is playing

If everything works fine, leave a comment here and we examine your old opera profile.

Comment: Yeah it works now! I think it had a lot to do with Flash. I remember having to muck with it a lot to get Chrome to work and they kept releasing many new versions recently. Adobe must be losing talent. I remember manually installing Flash and picking 'other' to test with IE, since Chrome has some bogus PepperFlash that was broken.